# Angular: Do not show object of array if there is a key "deactivated"

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting, filter

I have an array of objects generated via `JSON`. It looks like this:

```
{"uid":1,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"Surname","sex":1},
{"uid":2,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"Surname","sex":2},
{"uid":3,"first_name":"Name","last_name":"Surname","deactivated":"deleted","sex":1}
```

I scope them to `$scope.friends` and show via `ng-repeat="friend in friends"`.
I need to ignore all friends which contain key `deactivated` in their objects.

How can I do this?

Comment: Add a filter in ng-repeat :)

Comment: How should it look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: { deactivated: '!' }"
```